# Equivalent definitions of the positive fundamental unit.

Tags: number-theory

so I have these two definitions:

> The positive fundamental unit is the smallest element $\epsilon=x+y\sqrt{n}\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$ such that $x,y>0$ and $\text{Norm}(\epsilon)=1$

And the other one is

> The positive fundamental unit is the smallest $\epsilon>1$ such that $\text{Norm}(\epsilon)=1$

One direction is easy: 
If $\epsilon=x+y\sqrt{n}$ with $x,y>0$ and $\text{Norm}(\epsilon)=1$ then $x,y\geq1$ because they are integers and so $\epsilon >1$ and $\text{Norm}(\epsilon)=1$

But I am stuck in the other direction. Suppose now that $x+y\sqrt{n}>1$ and $\text{Norm}(\epsilon)=1$. Then $(x-y\sqrt{n})(x+y\sqrt{n})=1>(x-y\sqrt{n})>0 $ or $1>\overline{\epsilon}>0$. Then, my intuition concludes $x,y>0$ but how can I prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:
If $y = 0$, then $\epsilon = x = 1$, so $y \neq 0$. If $y < 0$, then $x-y\sqrt{n} > x + y \sqrt{n} > 1$ and hence $\operatorname{Norm}(\epsilon) > 1$, so $ y \not<0$. So, we conclude that $y > 0$.

Now, with $y > 0$, if $x \leq 0$, we should reach some easily derived contradictions...

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon = x + y \sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{n}]$.  Suppose $\epsilon > 1 and N(\epsilon) = 1$.  We want to show that $x$ and $y$ are both positive.

Let $\epsilon' = x - y \sqrt{n}$, so $1 = \epsilon \epsilon'$.

Suppose not.  Then say, $x$ is positive and $y$ is negative.  Then $\epsilon' > \epsilon > 1$.  This is impossible, since $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon'$ multiply to $1$.

On the other hand, $y$ could be positive and $x$ could be negative.  Then $-x + y \sqrt{n} > x + y \sqrt{n} > 1$, and $(-x + y \sqrt{n})(x + y \sqrt{n}) = -1$.  Again this is impossible, since the product of these numbers would have absolute value greater than $1$.